# Cordova Show Numeric Keyboard

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, numeric

I am working on a Cordova based application on an Android device. I need to bring up the numeric keyboard without the user having to click in the input box. I have tried several suggestions with no luck. I have the input type="number" which does bring up the keyboard when you click in the input box. I don't want my users to have to do that. I have tried the following:

Set type="number" and set focus to the control. Keyboard does not come up.

I created a plugin to create an EditText that was numeric and set focus on it. No keyboard.

I called the showSoftInput using an InputMethodManager. I get an alphanumeric keyboard.

I tried setting focus to the control and sending keystrokes from a plugin. No keyboard.

The only way I have find is by sending clicks to the screen from a plugin. The issue with this is that it is inconsistent, and you must keep up with coordinates.

Has anyone solved this?

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone already took a stab at a plugin that emulates the native touch event as to trigger the proper soft keyboard for the html input.

https://github.com/46cl/cordova-android-focus-plugin/

Comment: I just verify that the above plugin works, and have also submitted a PR to bring it up to compatibility with Cordova 4.0.0